# Why babel installation fails with syntax error?

Tags: javascript, npm, babeljs, npm-install, babel-loader

Does anyone know the reason why babel installations fails with bellow error?

[image]

The corresponding logs is here,

[image]

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I resolve the error, in my case npm was crashed, i reinstalled npm and everything started working back.

Answer (score 1):

I think this will Solve.

```
npm cache clean --force
```

or

```
yarn cache clean
```

then install npm

```
npm  install --save-dev @babel/cli @babel/preset-react
```

Comment: Cache clean did not worked to me, but i used yarn add and it works! Is this npm cache issue?